# Probability of picking from two bags

Tags: probability

Let there be two bags B1 and B2. If B1 has the letters A,B, C, D, and E and bag has U,V,W,X,Y, and Z, what is the probability of choosing A and Z.

Intuitively I though the probability is $\frac{1}{5\cdot{6}}=\frac{1}{30}$

Apparently the answer is $\frac{1}{15}$ Why does it appear twice?

Comment: You didn't say how we are choosing.  If, say, we choose one from each then I don't see any argument against your $\frac 1{30}$.  But you should explain how the choices are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the discussion in the comments has gotten rather lengthy, let me post my answer here.

I am assuming that we are choosing one from $B_1$ and one from $B_2$.  In that case, I'd say the answer was obviously $\frac 1{30}$ (agreeing with the OP).  Indeed, the only way to draw the pair $(A,Z)$ is to get $A$ as the $B_1$ selection (prob $=\frac 15$), AND get $Z$ as the $B_2$ selection (prob $=\frac 16$).  Thus the answer is the product $$\frac 15\times \frac 16=\frac 1{30}$$.

I believe people are confusing this situation with that of dice rolls.  In that case, there is generally a symmetry.  Thus, if I have an ordinary red die and an ordinary blue die, I can roll the unordered pair $(1,6)$ in two ways, doubling the apparent probability.  But the proper analogy for the current picture is to suppose that we have a fair red die with five faces $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and a fair blue die with faces $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$.  Now the probability of rolling a $(1,f)$ is $\frac 1{30}$, as there is only one way to it:  We need to get a red $1$ (prob $=\frac 15$) AND a blue $f$ (prob $=\frac 16$).

Answer (score 0):

Because you can pick A, then Z

OR Z then A

Comment: I don't understand.  There are $30$ possible pairs, yes?  If each pair has probability $\frac 1{15}$ of being chosen...well, doesn't that add to $2$?

Comment: @lulu 1/30 for A then Z, but Z then A puts you up to 2/30, which is equal to 1/15

Comment: Right...but, as I say, there are $30$ pairs in total.  $5$ from the first, $6$ from the second, and $5\times 6=30$.  Do you believe they each have probability $\frac 1{15}$?

Comment: The OP is silent, but I am assuming that you choose one from each bag.  Thus, to choose the pair $(A,Z)$ the bag $1$ choice must be $A$, prob $\frac 15$ AND the bag $2$ choice must be $Z$, prob $\frac 16$.  Hence the answer is $\frac 15 \times \frac 16 = \frac 1{30}$.  Are you picturing a different selection process?

Comment: @lulu but there are two ways of getting each combination!

Comment: The probability of picking $\{A,Z\}$ is $\frac1{15}$ and the probability for picking $(A,Z)$ is indeed $\frac1{30}$. So you're both right,just talking about a different question.

Comment: You are just repeating yourself.  You are thinking of the dice situation where (if one is red and the other blue) I might get a red $1$, blue $6$ or a red $6$, blue $1$ doubling the probability of getting the pair $(1,6)$.  But that picture doesn't apply here.  Instead picture a red die with faces $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and a blue die with faces $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$.  Now the probability of throwing the pair $(1,f)$ is $\frac 1{36}$ as there is only one way to throw it.

Comment: @JSchoone  Sorry, I don't think so.  Assuming we are just taking one from each bag (the OP really needs to specify this!) then there is only one way to draw the pair $(A,Z)$:  the bag $1$ choice must be $A$ and the bag $2$ choice must be $Z$.

Comment: @lulu So what do you think the probability of picking $\{ A, Z\}$ is?

Comment: @JSchoone  $\frac 1{30}$, of course.  There are $30$ possible pairs, all equally probable.

Comment: I'm sorry. You do pick one from each bag. But why does it double?

Comment: @lulu I am not speaking about pairs. So what is the probability of picking either $(A,Z)$ or $(Z,A)$?

Comment: @JSchoone As I say, $\frac 1{30}$.  Your two pairs coincide!  Either pair means that the bag $1$ choice was $A$ and the bag $2$ choice was $Z$.

Comment: I agree with lulu.

Comment: @JSchoone  Note:  it would be different if $A,Z$ were in both bags.  Then I'd buy that there were two different ways to get the desired selection.  As it is, your change in ordering is irrelevant...as I know for sure that the $A$ came from bag $1$ and the $Z$ came from bag $2$.

Comment: @Ian Then you should have specified in the question that you should first have picked an element from $B_1$ and then from $B_2$.

Comment: It was implied. You can only choose the A from B1 and Z from B2. Therefore, you pick in one bag and then the other. That is the question exactly.

Comment: @JSchoone  sorry to be argumentative, but you still aren't right.  It makes no difference at all which order you choose in (nor if you choose simultaneously, as with dice). There is no symmetry here...The $A$ can only come from bag $1$ and the $Z$ can only come from bag $2$.

Comment: @lulu Could it be an error? Well not could...it *is* an error.

Comment: @IanLimarta  Well, there's an error somewhere!  Is it possible that you have misstated the problem?  I suggest editing your post to include the question and answer exactly as they appear, without alteration.

Comment: @lulu I asked my friend to check my post.  There is no error.

Comment: @IanLimarta  Ok, well obviously we have no way to judge that.  What is the source of the problem?

Comment: My teacher wrote it